# How can I delete a history tree from local git

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have a remote repository A which I was modifying locally, later, accidentally I changed the remote repository to another one (remote repository B) and I pulled the history tree of the B repository.

Now, when I revert the reference to the A repository, I have two totally independet history trees in one. The B history tree has not branches, just the commit history with Tags.

How can I delete this commit history tree from my local repository?

Thank you!

Edit: I am using Git Extensions to visualize it.

Edit2: This is the branches of my local repository and none refers the repo B.

```
$ git branch -a
  DevUgaitz
  DragDropError
  SectionUpdate
* develop
  in.division
  master
  remotes/origin/DevUgaitz
  remotes/origin/MultMatrix
  remotes/origin/TestCD
  remotes/origin/TwoCardExecution
  remotes/origin/add.libs.to.launcher
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/in.division
  remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: _"The B history tree has not branches, just the commit history"_ what do you mean here? Do you know what branches are? And how they relate to commits? - Remember, _commits are the history_.

Comment: I'm going to ignore your tone of superiority, and try to explain better: If I list all branched there are not branched that refer to any commit of the B history. I hope now that can easier to understand. Thank you for comment!

Comment: Any tone is unintentional. I would expect if you remove all references to repo B, then repo B’s tree will be garbage collected.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion then. I try to run `git gc` but the repo B is not deleted.

Comment: May you share the output of `git branch -a`?

Comment: Added to the main question ;)

Comment: Do any of those branches point to repo b commits?

Comment: From what you have shown so far, I cannot see what would belong to repository A and what to repository B. How do you know that commit history of repository B is still there?

Comment: None of this refers repo b commit and there are totally independent (no one has child of parents in other tree)

Comment: @j6t I can visualize it using Git Extensions, maybe the problem is the visualization....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why the repo B was not deleted automatically or executing garbage collector. Repository B did not have branches that made references but it did have Tags, so deleting all tags is automatically deleted.

Thank all of you, for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch --prune` will remove the branches (history) from repo B

Comment: I try it but the history is not deleted